# JSON parsing problems undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
$.getJSON("hello.txt", function(json) {
    console.log(json); 
    alert(json.rgInventory[2].id);
});
```

Using the following code I am trying to parse JSON information from an hello.txt file, and display it. As you can see inn the picture under the code recognizes the JSON information correctly but when trying to print the id from the third element it the rgInventory object, it says undefined.

[image]

There is many objects inside this one with information and all have an ID. The JSON data I'm working with is available here: http://steamcommunity.com/id/flaangvik/inventory/json/730/2

Comment: Please post the JSON being returned in the request.

Comment: try to console.log(json.rgInventory);

Comment: This is the json -> http://steamcommunity.com/id/flaangvik/inventory/json/730/2

Comment: I can see in image that `rgInventory` is an `object` not an `array`. Why you have written `rgInventory[2]`

Comment: `rginventory` isn't an array, hence the `[2]` accessor doesn't work. What value are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: @HarshSanghani http://vvcap.com/ZAMqsHQEHq9 that seems to work fine, it gets the objects

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan trying to loop thru and get id from each object inside that object

Comment: try .each for that rgInventory

Comment: try to create loop as my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because in the JSON response `rgInventory` is an object, not an array.

> I am trying to loop thru and get id from each object inside that object

In this case you need to iterate through the object. Try this:

```
$.getJSON("hello.txt", function(json) {
    $.each(json.rgInventory, function(key, obj) {
        console.log(obj);
        var id = obj.id;
        // work with each object here...
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these code :-

```
$(json.rgInventory).each(function(key, value){
   console.log(value);
   // Do your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your JSON return, the *rgInventory* property from your return is an object instead of an array. You might need to access the child by the hash key instead of an index number.

JSON:

```
{"success":true,"rgInventory":{"4847011145":{"id":"4847011145","classid":"506870401","instanceid":"188530398","amount":"1","pos":1},"4846997498":{"id":"4846997498","classid":"653322524","instanceid":"188530248","amount":"1","pos":2},...
```

You should write:

```
$.getJSON("hello.txt", function(json) {
alert(json.rgInventory["4847011145"].id);
}
```